# Spring Boot Form request tracking

Tags: spring, forms, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am working on a Spring Boot MVC application and thinking of how to implement a solution for the *double form submit* problem.

The solution I'm thinking of is to generate a unique id and attach it to the form when a user requests it. Then when the user submits the form, compare the received id to the original and if they match, send it. If any more requests come in, I can see then that it is a double submit and reject the request.

The solution is simple, and I'm hoping I can find a simple implementation as well. I have about 8 different Thymeleaf forms I need to update by adding the unique ids, and I don't really want to add the ID to the POJOs backing the Thymeleaf forms. Is there a way I can add the unique ID to an http header that will be returned or something similar which won't require updating the Java Pojos?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can include a CSRF token in your form and Spring will take care of it automatically, though you might need to include Spring Security if you're not already using it in your project.

e.g.

```
<form>
    ...
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
</form>
```

[Official Spring documentation for CSRF with examples](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html)

Comment: Only problem with this approach is that CSRF tokens are session based. Meaning the user wouldn't be able to submit (after the first) any other forms until they've refreshed the session.
I could generate a new csrf every request, but I've read this leads to strange behavior in the web app (e.g. new tabs don't have the same tokens, etc)

Comment: Well, if you don't want to use a CSRF token, you can always use the  [Post/Redirect/Get pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Comment: I have already implemented the Post/Redirect/Get pattern, but it's only relevant for the page after form submit. It won't handle multiple submits before page navigation.
I ended up just adding the token to the forms individually, as I don't see a good alternative